# What method to use to learn a specific region in a signal data

Tags: python, keras

I am given with a set of following data:

- a list of nanopore signal data e.g. `[88.2, 92.5, ... 101.5]`
- a numerical value that tells where a specific material is located within the signal data e.g. 5 => that specific thing is located in the 5th index in the corresponding signal data.

I am trying to use `Keras` to implement Machine Learning with bidirectional `LSTM` models to learn the patterns between the signal data and the numerical index value.

I have read some sample codes on internet and tried to use them, but I am facing some issues. Not even sure if my approach is appropriate.

Since most of the codes I've read had equal dimensions of inputs and labels, I made an array of zeros that matches the length of signal data, and put 1 to the index value of the numerical value.

```
e.g. Signal = [1, 2, 4, 5]
     Label = [0, 0, 1, 0]
```

After such modification of the data, I tried implementing bidirectional LSTM, but I am receiving Value errors

```py
# signal_dataset = (3912, 24160) -> 3912 sequences with 24160 length
# label_dataset = (3912, 24160) -> 3912 sequences with 24160 length.

# Conversion to 3 dimension
sig_dataset = sig_dataset.reshape(1, len(sig_dataset), len(sig_dataset[0]))
lab_dataset = lab_dataset.reshape(1, len(lab_dataset), len(lab_dataset[0]))

train_size = int(len(sig_dataset) * 0.8)
trainX, trainY = sig_dataset[:train_size], adap_dataset[:train_size]
validX, validY = sig_dataset[train_size:], adap_dataset[train_size:]

# define LSTM
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(512, return_sequences=True), input_shape=(24160, 1)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', 
              optimizer='adam', 
              metrics=['acc'])

hist = model.fit(trainX, 
                 trainY, 
                 epochs=10, 
                 batch_size=1, 
                 validation_data=(validX, validY))
```

---

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected `bidirectional_32_input` to have 3 dimensions, but got array with `shape (3184, 24160)`

What am I doing wrong? Is this approach even correct? Please give me any advice

Comment: `sig_dataset = sig_dataset.reshape(1, len(sig_dataset), len(sig_dataset[0], 1))`